# Flutter: Get currently active TextEditingController without explicitly creating Controllers or Nodes

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, desktop, texteditingcontroller

**ATTENTION: Windows-Development here.**

I want to use a virtual keyboard (on screen). I can not rely on a hardware-keyboard.

My goal is to securely get any TextEditingController if I e.g. tap on a `TextFormField` so I can use it in my virtual keyboard (I use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/vk) plugin).

Currently my `VirtualKeyboard` is wrapped in a `Stack` as a `Positioned` and only shown if a `Focus`-change has been detected. This already works:

```dart
Focus(
    onFocusChange: ((value) {
      BlocProvider.of<KeyboardCubit>(context).setShow(value);
    }),
    child: Stack(...),
)
```

But I'm stuck on the part to get the `TextEditingController`. **I do not want to add custom code for every TextFormField**. Flutter achieves it somehow when pressing on something that may be focusable, so why can't I?

Maybe I am missing something. I am glad to hear your opinions.

Best regards.

Alternative Question:
Is there any good Virtual Keyboard plugin that handles this use case safely?

Comment: cannot you create a custom widget that creates `FocusNode` / `TextEditingController` and builds `TextFormField` with those two?

Comment: @pskink probably yes, but I don't want to replace every default widget with a custom widget. I think that flutter solves this somehow, and i **really** want to find out if I can do it without wrapping default widgets in some custom widgets.

Comment: If you can detect when a specific TextFormField has focus, you should know its controller.

Comment: @dante i can detect that there is focus but not where it comes from. Or at least i do not know. Maybe you do?

Comment: I found something from the `flutter_test`:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/simulateKeyDownEvent.html

Maybe we can make use of that?

Comment: see `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus` but still you have to assign unique `FocusNode` and `TextEditingController` for every `TextFormField` - how would you do that if not by setting `focusNode` and `controller` properties?

Comment: @pskink Flutter creates a `TextEditingController` if none is provided: "If null, this widget will create its own [TextEditingController] and (...)" Line 259 in `text_form_field.dart`. 
Think about it, if flutter can handle it implicitly, why can't i expose a currently selected/attached `TextEditingController`/`Node`? I want to know if it is possible